# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). But I am not returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to separate my components out so that I don't fetch data in a render function call.

So far, I've two functional components:

```
const Comment = ({data}) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        {data.map((comment, i) => (<li id={comment.id}>{comment.user.displayName}:{comment.text}</li>))}
    </React.Fragment>
);

const IssueComment = ({comment}) => {
    const [data, updateData] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const resp = await user.getUser(comment.createdByUserId)
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
            const json = resp.json()
            comment.user = json
            updateData(json);
        }
        getData();
    }, []);

    return data && <Comment data={data} />
}
```

When I run the React build, the page render fails with the above error message. I thought that I was containing the async stuff to `useEffect`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you console log data after await?

Comment: @WilliamWang whereabouts ?

Comment: just console.log(json) before updateData

Comment: @WilliamWang it still bombs out, nothing in the console is written

Comment: just update `return data && <Comment data={data} />` to `return <span></span>` temporarily and console log

Comment: @WilliamWang still fails with no output

Comment: useEffect(async () => { ... await getData(); }, []);

Comment: my hunch is that `json` is a promise and you're assigning it to `comment.user` and somewhere you're using `comment.user` as a child element.

Comment: `await resp.json()` - [`Response.json()` is a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), if you are using Fetch API in `getUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
return data && <Comment data={data} />
```

Conditional rendering works fine with boolean variables (or conditions), not with others, say for example

```
return 0 && <Comment data={data}/>
```

It will render 0, not nothing.

You need some check on your data, like:

```
return data==null && <Comment data={data} />
```

And as @5ar mentioned in comment to you, `.json()` is a promise, so you need to await that too, but still above is valid - that was the main reason why you had that error in first place

Comment: just as a side note, if you want to capture all falsy/truthy values casting the object to boolean like `return !!data && <Comment data={data} />` is also an option, but that's more a matter of style